# How to move block a right, and block b left with pure CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to know if the following is possible:

Move `block b to the left`, and move `block a to the right` with pure CSS(with our without flexbox) while the html is as follows:

```css
.text-container {width: 100%; display: flex;}
.a-block { width: 50%; }
.b-block { width: 50%; }
.b-block img { width: 100%; }
```

```html
<div class="text-container">
  <div class="a-block">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin maximus est eu nulla ullamcorper pulvinar. Vestibulum sem mi, tempor in metus vitae, iaculis volutpat purus. Donec at ex auctor, blandit mauris id, egestas ex. Aenean justo ipsum, commodo id accumsan sed, aliquet ac ante. Nam sagittis consequat consectetur. Nullam fringilla, nunc ac tempus fermentum, ante ipsum varius tortor, eget convallis libero metus vitae dolor. Phasellus tempor, turpis faucibus hendrerit ullamcorper, leo nibh commodo metus, a interdum nunc metus quis mauris. Proin libero nisl, consequat sed venenatis at, vehicula eu neque. Nulla ac eleifend risus. Vestibulum rutrum faucibus massa nec vulputate. 
  </div>

  <div class="b-block">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/kaXCm6C.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Personally, I thought I could move them by simple using float, `block a float: right, block b float: left`, unfortunately that did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using `flex`, you can use `order` property

The CSS `order` property specifies the order used to lay out flex items in their flex container. Elements are laid out in the ascending order of the order value. Elements with the same order value are laid out in the order in which they appear in the source code.

```css
.text-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.a-block {
  width: 50%;
  order: 1;
}

.b-block {
  width: 50%;
  order: 0;
}

.b-block img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-container">
  <div class="a-block">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin maximus est eu nulla ullamcorper pulvinar. Vestibulum sem mi, tempor in metus vitae, iaculis volutpat purus. Donec at ex auctor, blandit mauris id, egestas ex. Aenean justo ipsum, commodo
    id accumsan sed, aliquet ac ante. Nam sagittis consequat consectetur. Nullam fringilla, nunc ac tempus fermentum, ante ipsum varius tortor, eget convallis libero metus vitae dolor. Phasellus tempor, turpis faucibus hendrerit ullamcorper, leo nibh
    commodo metus, a interdum nunc metus quis mauris. Proin libero nisl, consequat sed venenatis at, vehicula eu neque. Nulla ac eleifend risus. Vestibulum rutrum faucibus massa nec vulputate.
  </div>

  <div class="b-block">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/kaXCm6C.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

for more info : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/order

Comment: Thanks, I honestly looked at the documentation on how to order the divs because I knew flexbox had this functionality but I could not find it for anything. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You Need to add one CSS  **(flex-direction: row-reverse;)** to reverse the position of the div.

**Your Modified Code:**

```css
.text-container {width: 100%; display: flex; flex-direction: row-reverse;}
.a-block { width: 50%; }
.b-block { width: 50%; }
.b-block img { width: 100%; }
```

```html
<div class="text-container">
  <div class="a-block">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin maximus est eu nulla ullamcorper pulvinar. Vestibulum sem mi, tempor in metus vitae, iaculis volutpat purus. Donec at ex auctor, blandit mauris id, egestas ex. Aenean justo ipsum, commodo id accumsan sed, aliquet ac ante. Nam sagittis consequat consectetur. Nullam fringilla, nunc ac tempus fermentum, ante ipsum varius tortor, eget convallis libero metus vitae dolor. Phasellus tempor, turpis faucibus hendrerit ullamcorper, leo nibh commodo metus, a interdum nunc metus quis mauris. Proin libero nisl, consequat sed venenatis at, vehicula eu neque. Nulla ac eleifend risus. Vestibulum rutrum faucibus massa nec vulputate. 
  </div>

  <div class="b-block">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/kaXCm6C.png">
  </div>
</div>
```